# It is possible to decompile .pyc files on version 3.12 alpha 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, decompiling

I've only found decompilers for 3.10 and below, but is it possible to get the source from a 3.12 alpha 2 .pyc file?

I tried uncompyle6, decompyle3, pycdc but they are all for other python versions

Comment: I would be glad if I found a decompiler for at least 3.11

Comment: Added the cpython tag since `.pyc` files are an implementation detail of CPython

Answer (score -2):

Try this C++ implementation.
https://github.com/zrax/pycdc : The README for this C++ code says it aims to support all versions of Python.

This code is best for Python versions around 2.7 and 3.3 when the code was initially developed. Accuracy for current versions of Python3 and early versions of Python is lacking. Without major effort, it is unlikely it can be made to support current Python 3. See its issue tracker for details. Currently lightly maintained.

Anyway worth to try it.

Comment: That repo has an open issue(s) for Python 3.11 compatibility. It doesn't seem to meet the OPs requirements for a Python 3.11 or 3.12 decompiler.

Comment: That's what I said "Without major effort, it is unlikely it can be made to support current Python 3. See its issue tracker for details. "